# Where are the node objects stored on the node's local file system?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I reading [this doc](https://docs.chef.io/nodes.html) and it s

> The chef-client pulls down the node object from the Chef server. If
>   this is the first chef-client run for the node, there will not be a
>   node object to pull down from the Chef server. After the node object
>   is pulled down from the Chef server, the chef-client rebuilds the node
>   object. If this is the first chef-client run for the node, the rebuilt
>   node object will contain only the default run-list. For any subsequent
>   chef-client run, the rebuilt node object will also contain the
>   run-list from the previous chef-client run.

The node must store the node object (json file) locally somewhere right? I look in C:\chef\cache on one of my nodes and I don't see it.

Is there somewhere on the nodes' file systems where these node objects are stored/cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is only stored in memory.

You can extract it yourself via something like:

```
file Chef::Config[:file_cache_path] + "/node.json" do
  content Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(node.to_hash)
end
```

Comment: Note that you probably don't really want to do that -- typically you use knife from the command line to interact with the node object on the server.